# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I am learning objective-c and do not know what this code does. I understand what UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer does. However, I am confused as to what this code is doing with the UIScreenEdgePanGesture.

```
UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *rightRecog = 
[[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resetChart:)];
[rightRecog setEdges:UIRectEdgeRight];
[rightRecog setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];

[self.chartView addGestureRecognizer:rightRecog];

UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *leftRecog = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resetChart:)];

[leftRecog setEdges:UIRectEdgeLeft];
[leftRecog setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];

[self.chartView addGestureRecognizer:leftRecog];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a code pattern used to define a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that checks for finger/pen touches on the **devices screen edges** from right inside and from left inside the screen center but will cancel any touch event happening inside the view the same time.

The recognizer binds to `self.chartView` to observe those gestures.

It also defines a method `@selector(resetChart:)` that will act (action) in case the fingers are sliding in on one side of the chartView. But the method `-resetChart:` will be part of the ViewController Class or View Class you defined the recogniser inside defined as (`self`).

```
UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *rightRecog = 
[[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resetChart:)];
[rightRecog setEdges:UIRectEdgeRight];
[rightRecog setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];
[self.chartView addGestureRecognizer:rightRecog];
```

the above code is setting up the recognizer from the right side.
The code below does the same thing for the left side but will trigger the same method.

```
UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *leftRecog = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resetChart:)];
[leftRecog setEdges:UIRectEdgeLeft];
[leftRecog setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];
[self.chartView addGestureRecognizer:leftRecog];
```

so it could be melt together like so..

```
UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *rightLeftRecog =
[[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resetChart:)];
[rightLeftRecog setEdges:UIRectEdgeRight|UIRectEdgeLeft];
[rightLeftRecog setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];
[self.chartView addGestureRecognizer:rightLeftRecog];
```

because `-resetChart:` is just doing the same.

which will look like

```
-(void)resetChart:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    //do some stuff with the gesture or amount of fingers used.
}
```